# Is it possible to trigger Google Assistant to say things via 3rd party?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant, domoticz

Basically I want to make my Google home device make an announcement when my mail arrives via Domoticz sensor.

I know IFTTT can trigger Domoticz via web URL but is there a function to trigger Google Assistant in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send commands to a Google Home device on the same network to play a MP3 from a URL. With this you can have the Home Device play arbitrary messages.

There are libraries to do this e.g. for nodejs [google-home-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-home-notify) that takes a string, sends it to Google's Text to Speech API and then has the Google Home play the output.

The [example](https://github.com/nabbl/google-home-notifier/blob/master/examples/sendsimpletext.js) code for this node is very simple:

```
var googlehomenotifier = require('../')("192.168.178.131", "en-US", 1);

googlehomenotifier.notify("Some crazy textmessage", function (result) {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Where `192.168.178.131` is the IP address of the Google Home device on your local network.

There is also a Python [version](https://github.com/harperreed/google-home-notifier-python) that might plug into Domoticz easier.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.  I found some discussion that looked promising here as well:  https://community.smartthings.com/t/google-home-respond-to-a-trigger/125794/12

Comment: I currently use HomeAssistant which has a built in process to send TTS commands to my local google home device.  It can also send TTS commands to my Android phone which is amazing!